# What is the value of $\int_{-2}^3\min\{1,x^2\}dx$

Tags: calculus

I have another question:

What is the value of $$\int_{-2}^3\min\{1,x^2\}dx$$

Thanks your help!

Comment: I'd suggest starting by figuring out what your function actually looks like, and then compute the integral by thinking about area under the curve.  For starters, when $|x| < 1$, we have $\min(1, x^2) = x^2$.  Otherwise, if $|x| > 1$, then $\min(1, x^2) = 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$x^2 <1 \Rightarrow |x| < 1$. Therefore

$$\int^3_{-2}\min\{1,x^2\}\,dx = \int^{-1}_{-2}1\, dx + \int^{1}_{-1}x^2\,dx + \int^{3}_{1}1\,dx$$

Answer (score 4):

Since $$\min\{1,x^2\}=\begin{cases}
1 & x\in[1,3]\\
x^2 & x \in(-1,1)\\
1 & x\in[-2,-1]
\end{cases}$$
you have $$\int_{-2}^3\min\{1,x^2\}dx= \int_{-2}^{-1}dx+\int_{-1}^1x^2dx+\int_1^3dx=11/3$$